# Pyspark divide column by its subtotals grouped by another column

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, calculated-field

My problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50493426/pyspark-divide-column-by-its-sum?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552672/how-to-divide-a-column-by-its-sum-in-a-spark-dataframe). Both posts show how to divide a column value by the total sum of the same column. In my case I want to divide the values of a column by the sum of subtotals. Subtotal is calculated by grouping the column values depending on another column. I am slightly modifying the example mentioned in the links shared above.

Here is my dataframe

```
df = [[1,'CAT1',10], [2, 'CAT1', 11], [3, 'CAT2', 20], [4, 'CAT2', 22], [5, 'CAT3', 30]]
df = spark.createDataFrame(df, ['id', 'category', 'consumption'])
df.show()
+---+--------+-----------+
| id|category|consumption|
+---+--------+-----------+
|  1|    CAT1|         10|
|  2|    CAT1|         11|
|  3|    CAT2|         20|
|  4|    CAT2|         22|
|  5|    CAT3|         30|
+---+--------+-----------+
```

I want to divide "consumption" value by the total of grouped "category" and put the value in a column "normalized" as below.

The subtotals doesn't need to be in the output(number 21, 42 and 30 in column consumption)
[image]

What I've achieved so far
df.crossJoin(

```
df.groupby('category').agg(F.sum('consumption').alias('sum_'))
).withColumn("normalized", F.col("consumption")/F.col("sum_"))\
.show()

+---+--------+-----------+--------+----+-------------------+
| id|category|consumption|category|sum_|         normalized|
+---+--------+-----------+--------+----+-------------------+
|  1|    CAT1|         10|    CAT2|  42|0.23809523809523808|
|  2|    CAT1|         11|    CAT2|  42| 0.2619047619047619|
|  1|    CAT1|         10|    CAT1|  21|0.47619047619047616|
|  2|    CAT1|         11|    CAT1|  21| 0.5238095238095238|
|  1|    CAT1|         10|    CAT3|  30| 0.3333333333333333|
|  2|    CAT1|         11|    CAT3|  30|0.36666666666666664|
|  3|    CAT2|         20|    CAT2|  42|0.47619047619047616|
|  4|    CAT2|         22|    CAT2|  42| 0.5238095238095238|
|  5|    CAT3|         30|    CAT2|  42| 0.7142857142857143|
|  3|    CAT2|         20|    CAT1|  21| 0.9523809523809523|
|  4|    CAT2|         22|    CAT1|  21| 1.0476190476190477|
|  5|    CAT3|         30|    CAT1|  21| 1.4285714285714286|
|  3|    CAT2|         20|    CAT3|  30| 0.6666666666666666|
|  4|    CAT2|         22|    CAT3|  30| 0.7333333333333333|
|  5|    CAT3|         30|    CAT3|  30|                1.0|
+---+--------+-----------+--------+----+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do basically the same as in the links you have already mentioned. The only difference is that you have to calculate the subtotals before with [groupby](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=selectexpr#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.groupBy) and [sum](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=selectexpr#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.sum):

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = df.join(df.groupby('category').sum('consumption'), 'category')
df = df.select('id', 'category', F.round(F.col('consumption')/F.col('sum(consumption)'), 2).alias('normalized'))
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+--------+----------+ 
| id|category|normalized| 
+---+--------+----------+ 
|  3|    CAT2|      0.48| 
|  4|    CAT2|      0.52| 
|  1|    CAT1|      0.48| 
|  2|    CAT1|      0.52| 
|  5|    CAT3|       1.0| 
+---+--------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another way of solving the problem as proposed by the `OP`, but without using `joins()`.

`joins()` in general are costly operations and should be avoided when ever possible.

```
# We first register our DataFrame as temporary SQL view
df.registerTempTable('table_view')
df = sqlContext.sql("""select id, category, 
                       consumption/sum(consumption) over (partition by category) as normalize
                       from table_view""")
df.show()
+---+--------+-------------------+
| id|category|          normalize|
+---+--------+-------------------+
|  3|    CAT2|0.47619047619047616|
|  4|    CAT2| 0.5238095238095238|
|  1|    CAT1|0.47619047619047616|
|  2|    CAT1| 0.5238095238095238|
|  5|    CAT3|                1.0|
+---+--------+-------------------+
```

*Note:* ["""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40787972/how-to-execute-multi-line-sql-in-spark-sql) has been used to have multiline statements for the sake of visibility and neatness. With simple `'select id ....'` that wouldn't work if you try to spread your statement over multiple lines. Needless to say, the final result will be the same.

Comment: Never occurred to me that I can use over and partition by - neat solution